# jQuery on PartialView (asp.net mvc 4)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project with an Index page that list items.
Each item has a link to load a Detail page as partial view via $.ajax()

That partial view shows perfectly and has a link to load another view in the same div that the first partial view.

My problem is the that the second link don't works as partial view, it loads as a new html page.

I don't know how to load a partial view from another partial view via with no reload the page.

Thank you.

This is my view code for the first links:

```
    <div class="span5">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Código", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.CodigoSortParm })
                    @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Codigo)*@
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Detalle", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DetalleSortParm })
                    @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Detalle)*@
                </th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                @*version de tr que permite la edicion haciendo click en la fila
                <tr data-href="@Url.Action("Edit", "CondicionIva", new { id = item.CondicionIvaID })">*@
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Codigo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Detalle)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Detalles", "Details",null, new { id = item.CondicionIvaID },new {@class ="linkContainer2"})
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

```
    <div class="span6" id="divContainer2">
    </div>
```

Comment: I think I understand, can you post you code for where you bind to the first set of links please?

Comment: I was leaning more to the javascript/jQuery code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starter, I think what you're trying to achieve is pulling some html from a server (after the DOM is loaded), which contains links, and you want them to behave like the initial links that are dynamically loading the content?

I think what you're after is when you're binding to youre links with jQuery - you need to be using the '.on' method

> [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Use this in the syntax:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     //call $.ajax here

    return false;//for good measure
});
```

Comment: Great! glad I could help :) flag as answer ;)